# Scrapy error: "scrapy 2.0.1 requires Python 3.5"

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, atom-editor

My python version is Python 3.7.7 and scrapy requires Python 3.5 or above, yet in Atom I'm getting the following error:

> "scrapy 2.0.1 requires Python 3.5"

I have previously had trouble with Atom defaulting to Python2, so have already updated python.coffee command to 'python3'.

Comment: Is uninstalling your other Pythons an option? That seems best.

Comment: Or switch to [a real python editor](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/)

Comment: How are you running the program in Atom? Are you using an extension like `script`? What command exactly are you using to run the script? Does the script have a shebang and if so what is it?

Comment: @wjandrea Yes, I'm using Script, cmd-i to run the program.

Comment: Find out how to get Atom to use your Python 3.7 installation, it looks like it is using Python 2 instead.

Answer (score 0):

uninstall python 2.x can solve this problem